# Disable SharePoint Site Managment log-in prompt

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

I've set up two sites using SharePoint. However, certian pages that require Administration privileges, when visited by end-users trigger a log in prompt. When contacting my vendor, he told me it's a normal behaviour as audience can use all features without login to the site.

Can it be completely disabled? any input small or large is apperciated.

[image]

Comment: Please check this document to see if it helps you?https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/sharepoint-keeps-asking-for-password.html